# What's the Chinese equivalent of Strunk and White's The Elements of Style?

Tags: resources, reference-materials

> [*The Elements of Style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) is a style guide to writing American English, published in numerous editions. ... *The Elements of Style* was listed as one of the 100 best and most influential books written in English since 1923 by Time in its 2011 list.

Strunk and White is considered a pivotal English writing style guide.  It generally doesn't say "X is wrong and Y is right", but rather than "Y is preferred over X for [reasons]" in cases where X and Y are both right.

I'm looking for the same thing but for Chinese, i.e., a pivotal Chinese writing style guide, which describes best practices for Chinese writing.

**Question**: What's the Chinese equivalent of Strunk and White's *The Elements of Style*?

Just to make this explicit: I'm *not* asking for a Chinese translation of Strunk and White, like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/780109641X).  I'm asking for the best-known Chinese writing style guide(s).  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%27s+the+Chinese+equivalent+of+Strunk+and+White%27s+The+Elements+of+Style%3F) just gives me translations.

Comment: Oops!  I didn't see the duplicate until after posting.